# Existence and uniqueness of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{xy} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the regions for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{xy} $ for which the solution is unique, with graph passing through
the point $(x_0, y_0)$ in these regions.

I tried to applied Picard theorem for existence and uniqueness. The function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt x}{2 \sqrt y}$ is defined when $xy\geq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ thus we have existence and uniqueness in the
regions $R = [0, \infty)\times (0, \infty)$ and $R = (-\infty, 0]\times (-\infty, 0)$ for any $(x_0, y_0)  \in R$.

However, answer is $R = (0, \infty)\times (0, \infty)$  and $R = (-\infty, 0)\times (-\infty, 0)$.

My question is why not $x=0$ is included in the region of existence and uniquness?

Thank you

Comment: That's because $y(x)=\frac19x^3$ and $y(x)=0$ are two different solutions with $y(0)=0.$

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for the comment. Could you right the answer with more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The only reason to exclude $x=0$ would be that the requested regions have to be open sets by the definition of the term "region" or "domain of the ODE".

This could be also be implied in

> "*graph passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ in these regions*"

because to "pass through" there needs to be a left and right of $x_0$, resp. $x_0$ needs to be an inner point of the domain of the solution, which is not given if $x_0=0$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood completely.

Answer (score 2):

The function $y(x)=0$ for all $x$ is a solution. So from now on we consider only functions with $y(x)\neq 0$ for some $x$. For points with $y(x)\neq 0$ we have
\begin{equation}\sqrt{x}=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}=(2\sqrt{y})',
\end{equation}
so integrating both sides yields
\begin{equation}\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+C=2\sqrt{y},
\end{equation}
which impliess
\begin{equation}y=\left(\frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+c \right)^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the analysis.